# How to pass an array from django views to external JS file for chart

Tags: javascript, html, django, charts, django-views

I am designing a dashboard where i need to pass labels and data to my chart from django views
to Variables in Java Script. This below code is not displaying lables or data in chart.

when i pass values directly into JS it works. But when same values passed through views.py it throws error in console like :
( jQuery.Deferred exception: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'getContext') TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'getContext'))

**Django Views**

```
def chartd(request):
    labelss=["JAN", "FEB", "MAR", "APR", "MAY", "JUN", "JUL", "AUG", "SEP", "OCT", "NOV", "DEC"]
    datas = [170, 123, 125, 90, 92, 70, 75, 60, 90, 80, 110, 100]
    context = {"labelss": mark_safe(json.dumps(labelss)), "datas": mark_safe(json.dumps(datas))}
    return render(request, 'charts.html',context)
```

**Java Script  for  charts.html**

```
  var chart_labels =JSON.parse('{{labelss}}');
  var chart_data =JSON.parse('{{datas}}');

    var ctx = document.getElementById("chartBig1").getContext('2d');

    var gradientStroke = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 230, 0, 50);

    gradientStroke.addColorStop(1, 'rgba(72,72,176,0.1)');
    gradientStroke.addColorStop(0.4, 'rgba(72,72,176,0.0)');
    gradientStroke.addColorStop(0, 'rgba(119,52,169,0)'); //purple colors
    var config = {
      type: 'line',
      data: {
        labels: chart_labels,
        datasets: [{
          label: "My First dataset",
          fill: true,
          backgroundColor: gradientStroke,
          borderColor: '#d346b1',
          borderWidth: 2,
          borderDash: [],
          borderDashOffset: 0.0,
          pointBackgroundColor: '#d346b1',
          pointBorderColor: 'rgba(255,255,255,0)',
          pointHoverBackgroundColor: '#d346b1',
          pointBorderWidth: 20,
          pointHoverRadius: 4,
          pointHoverBorderWidth: 15,
          pointRadius: 4,
          data: chart_data
        }]
      }
      options: gradientChartOptionsConfigurationWithTooltipPurple
    };
    var myChartData = new Chart(ctx, config);
    $("#0").click(function() {
      var data = myChartData.config.data;
      data.datasets[0].data = chart_data;
      data.labels = chart_labels;
      myChartData.update();
    });
    $("#1").click(function() {
      var chart_data = [80, 120, 105, 110, 95, 105, 90, 100, 80, 95, 70, 120];
      var data = myChartData.config.data;
      data.datasets[0].data = chart_data;
      data.labels = chart_labels;
      myChartData.update();
    });

    $("#2").click(function() {
      var chart_data = [60, 80, 65, 130, 80, 105, 90, 130, 70, 115, 60, 130];
      var data = myChartData.config.data;
      data.datasets[0].data = chart_data;
      data.labels = chart_labels;
      myChartData.update();
    });
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python list does not work in django with ChartJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67129192/python-list-does-not-work-in-django-with-chartjs)

Comment: Another one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66164015/how-to-pass-variable-list-to-javascript-in-django

Comment: I tried everything! It returns only empty string to JS...

Answer (score 0):

Can be done like this:

```py
def chartd(request):
    labelss=['JANS', 'FEBS', 'MARS', 'APRS', 'MAYS', 'JUN', 'JUL', 'AUG', 'SEP', 'OCT', 'NOV', 'DEC']
    datas = [120, 123, 125, 90, 92, 70, 75, 60, 90, 80, 110, 100]
    context = {"labelss": mark_safe(json.dumps(labelss)), "datas": mark_safe(json.dumps(datas))}
    return render(request, 'charts.html',context)
```

`labelss` and `datas` are json strings now

```html
<script>
var chart_labels =JSON.parse('{{labelss}}');
var chart_data =JSON.parse('{{datas}}');
</script>
```

and in JS/HTMl file you will convert json strings back to objects.

but better approach is just make view that returns JsonResponse and call it from JS using fetch.

UPDATE: test if data from view are same as manually set(for testing).

```html
<script>
  // from Django's view
  var chart_labels = JSON.parse('{{labelss}}');
  var chart_data = JSON.parse('{{datas}}');

  // manually set
  var chart_labels2 = ["JANS", "FEBS", "MARS", "APRS", "MAYS", "JUN", "JUL", "AUG", "SEP", "OCT", "NOV", "DEC"];
  var chart_data2 = [120, 123, 125, 90, 92, 70, 75, 60, 90, 80, 110, 100];

  // check if same
  console.log(JSON.stringify(chart_labels) === JSON.stringify(chart_labels2));
  // returns true
  console.log(JSON.stringify(chart_data) === JSON.stringify(chart_data2));
  // returns true
</script>
```

**Fully working** example:

views.py

```py
def chartd(request):
    labelss = ["JANS", "FEBS", "MARS", "APRS", "MAYS", "JUN", "JUL", "AUG", "SEP", "OCT", "NOV", "DEC"]
    datas = [120, 123, 125, 90, 92, 70, 75, 60, 90, 80, 110, 100]
    context = {"labelss": mark_safe(json.dumps(labelss)), "datas": mark_safe(json.dumps(datas))}
    return render(request, "charts.html", context)
```

charts.js

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Chart</title>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@3.6.0/dist/chart.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<canvas id="chart1"></canvas>
<script>
  // from Django's view
  var chart_labels = JSON.parse('{{labelss}}');
  var chart_data = JSON.parse('{{datas}}');

  var ctx = document.getElementById("chart1").getContext('2d');
  var gradientStroke = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 230, 0, 50);
  gradientStroke.addColorStop(1, "rgba(72,72,176,0.1)");
  gradientStroke.addColorStop(0.4, "rgba(72,72,176,0.0)");
  gradientStroke.addColorStop(0, "rgba(119,52,169,0)"); //purple colors
  var config = {
    type: "line",
    data: {
      labels: chart_labels,
      datasets: [{
        label: "dataset",
        fill: true,
        backgroundColor: gradientStroke,
        borderColor: "#d346b1",
        borderWidth: 2,
        borderDash: [],
        borderDashOffset: 0.0,
        pointBackgroundColor: "#d346b1",
        pointBorderColor: "rgba(255,255,255,0)",
        pointHoverBackgroundColor: "#d346b1",
        pointBorderWidth: 20,
        pointHoverRadius: 4,
        pointHoverBorderWidth: 15,
        pointRadius: 4,
        data: chart_data
      }]
    }
  };
  new Chart(ctx, config);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: This didn't work. when it gets saved in var chart_labels and chart data it should be same as  
 ['JANS', 'FEBS', 'MARS', 'APRS', 'MAYS', 'JUN', 'JUL', 'AUG', 'SEP', 'OCT', 'NOV', 'DEC']  ,     [120, 123, 125, 90, 92, 70, 75, 60, 90, 80, 110, 100]   datatypes  or else chart don't fetch these values

Comment: @harishkrishna it's same as if you set it manually. Check if your chart works if you set these values manually because data from view are valid. I updated my answer so you can see it.

Comment: Hi, please check this. When i give same values manually it works but from views its thows error in console : (charts.html:1296 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier)

Comment: console log information gives empty string  " " @zelenyjan

Comment: If you know JsonResponse, help me out using that in this scenario.

Comment: The example above works as it is. You probably have error somewhere else... Take it as it is(the view function and whole charts.html file) in the example above and start from it. I just check again and it works fine. Btw: what's on line 1296 where you got Uncaught SyntaxError?

Comment: I am getting empty string in JS. So labelss[0 or anything] gives me undefined.

Comment: Really not sure what you're doing wrong because it works as it is in my answer. Just check if you have `mark_safe(json.dumps(labelss))`. It's important to use both `mark_safe` and `json.dumps`. Then in HTML file just check you have `JSON.parse('{{labelss}}')`. quotation marks around `{{ labelss }}` are required also `JSON.parse` part